# React Native slide out panel and scrollview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, react-native

I am developing an app with react native. I have this UI element which is similar to that of Maps in iOS, in which you slide a panel from the bottom and inside it, there is a scrollable list.

For the slide-out panel, I am using a component called `rn-sliding-up-panel`. It has several props as event listeners. For example

```js
<SlidingUpPanel
  allowDragging={/*Boolean*/}
  onDragStart={()=>{}   /*When it is about to be dragged*/}
  onDrag={()=>{} /*When it is being dragged*/}
  onDragEnd={()={} /*When the user is no longer touching the screen*/}
></SlidingUpPanel>
```

Inside it, I have a `<ScrollView>` containing a `<List>` from `react-native-elements`. As far as I know, it has only one vent listener, being:

```js
<ScrollView onScroll={()=>{}}></ScrollView>
```

---

My issue is that scrolling on the list actually causes the panel to close (it closes by sliding down). I found a work-around by adding a state, and modfiying it onScroll:

```js
state = {
  dragPanel: true,
}
/*===========================================*/
<SlidingUpPanel allowDragging={this.state.dragPanel}>
     <ScrollView onScroll={()={ this.setState({dragPanel: false}) }}></ScrollView>
</SlidingUpPanel>
```

However, I cannot find a way to restore the dragging, and it doesn't fire up as efficiently.

TL;DR

Is there an eficient way to implement a ScrollView inside a SlidingUpPanel without the events of each overlapping? Maybe using something similar to `function(e){e.preventDefault();}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To properly disable / restore outer scroll dragging, do

```js
_onGrant() {
  this.setState({ dragPanel: false });
  return true;
}

_onRelease() {
  this.setState({ dragPanel: true });
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this._onGrant = this._onGrant.bind(this);
  this._onRelease = this._onRelease.bind(this);

  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: this._onGrant,
    onPanResponderRelease: this._onRelease,
    onPanResponderTerminate: this._onRelease,
  });
}

render() {
  <SlidingUpPanel allowDragging={this.state.dragPanel}>
    <ScrollView
      {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    />
  </SlidingUpPanel>
}
```

From what I had been searching for a long time, `preventDefault()` is a pure web-javascript thing, I think there are no `preventDefault` in *react-native*.

From document section [Handling Touches](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html), *react-native* just use javascript to simulate Objc (iOS) & Java (Android) events.

Comment: Thanks for answering. From what I understand, `_onGrant()` should be fired when the user starts scrolling, and `_onRelease()` when the user stops scrolling. And `this._panResponder` fires them up accordingly. However, how should I implement it into the `<ScrollView>`?? (That is, no property name or anything?)

Comment: @edvilme `{...this._panResponder.panHandlers}` does exactly what you describe. that called *transferring props* https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to solve the issue. It helped me though,I added an event listener to a handle and rejected dragging in all the scroll events. Thank you!!!

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you! However if there are any child views inside the ScrollView, they need the same PanResponder added to them as well. I also had to add the onGrant method to the PanResponders onStartShouldSetPanResponder function otherwise it was flaky.

Answer (score 0):

Set the minimumDistanceThreshold property to something around 50. Maybe 30 for small screens and 50-60 for bigger ones. Do it like so:

```js
<SlidingUpPanel minimumDistanceThreshold={isSmallScreen ? 30 : 50}>
  <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
  </ScrollView> 
</SlidingUpPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be late for an answer but use your scroll view as absolute positioned and position it accordingly.

Think of the scroll view as a pop-up dialog that appears in front of the backdrop behind it. Upon clicking the backdrop, the pop-up dismisses. Apply similar logic to the issue by letting scroll view in front of the slide up panel.